# Click signatures on outlook how can i get its content

Tags: outlook, signature, mailitem

[image]

I add content with my Outlook mailitem, but the signature is sometimes at the top, sometimes it is at the bottom, so when I click the signature buttons in the picture, I want to take the content of the signature and add it to the bottom.

Answer (score 1):

Signatures are kept on the disk. By default you can find the `Signatures` folder in the following location:

```
C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Signatures
```

If you want to backup just a single signature, look for the following files and folders;

- `<signature_name>.htm` - This file is used when creating HTML messages.
- `<signature_name>.rtf` - This file is used when creating Rich Text messages.
- `<signature_name>.txt` - This file is used when creating Plain Text message.
- `<signature_name>_files` - This folder is used to store supporting files for your signature such as formatting, images and/or business cards (vcf-files).

So, you may read the signature files and detect where it has been added in the email.

Comment: thank u,How can I find or get the signature chosen from the menu, for example how can I get my 5 signature signed in third sign and I can take the name of the third signature and pull it in that file and print it on the signature